# Error occurred - status 503 returned

Tags: bug, review, edits, voting

I have been encountering:

[image: An error has occurred - please retry your request]

Looking in the Chrome console when this happens, I see:

[image: status 503 (backend read error)]

That particular example occurred on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) when voting to delete a comment. I have also had it when voting on questions and answers.

I have had these red box errors in the past on the odd occasion, but it seems to be much more frequent over the past day or two. I've only recently learned about the Chrome console (thanks Shog9 & ArtOfCode), so I can't say if past errors would have had the same detail.

While editing this question to respond to a comment, I received:

[image: An error occurred submitting the edit]

with:

[image: status 503 (backend read error)]

So it seems not to be limited to the site where I am a moderator. Logging out of Stack Exchange everywhere and clearing all my sessions and cookies did not resolve the problem.

Latest example:

[image: An error occurred while loading the review item]

[image: status 503 (backend read error)]

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in?

Comment: hmm... so weird. Let's hope a developer will take a look soon and fix it. :)

Comment: @nicael A physicist, a chemist, and a programmer were in a car that wouldn't start. The physicist examined the spark plugs and the engine; the chemist assessed the chemical makeup of the diesel and the oil; the programmer got out of the car and then went back in again.

Comment: @randal'  lol :D

Comment: looks like a network blip

Comment: @Sklivvz: except that SO recently switched CDN proxy providers and we've been seeing all manner of issues around that. Are you sure it is a network blip and not another timeout race?

Comment: We've added some indexing that should help with this. Can you let us know if this is still happening?

Comment: Ugh. And nothing in the exception logs :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I originally thought it was an internal network blip between our load balancers and the web servers. It turns out that another explanation is likely correct.

First of all, we've upgraded SQL Server to 2016 last week. This is great for a number of reasons, but we (and by "we" I mostly mean Nick Craver) have been chasing performance issues since then.

Secondly, having switched to [fastly](https://www.fastly.com/), slow performance might be reported to users as 503, whereas we don't see corresponding exceptions in the logs.

We're on it.